# branching ideas for concurrent team development?

Tags: tfs, concurrency, branching-and-merging

Anyone have some good pointers on how to get multiple teams doing concurrent asp.net development using Microsoft TFS?

i have been using subversion for the past many years now and it allowed my team to work freely without exclusively locking files and doing auto merges when possible (like 99% of the time)

but this all falls apart when my new team is forced to use TFS with exclusive locks...

any thoughts?

i am trying to get three development teams working on a big project together and want to do it with branching so we don't over-write changes and work efficiently.

Comment: It sounds more like your TFS environment is configured incorrectly if you are forced to exclusively lock files when you check-out a file. 

Are multiple check-out disabled for your tfs projects?

Answer (score -1):

- TFS can work without exclusive locks. Seriously. If you CAN work with it (as in: non-exclusive locks have their own share of problems), TFS will work like that.

For many scenarios, though, non-exclusive checkouts simply do not work (logically) because the merging is too complicated.

> i am trying to get three development
>   teams working on a big project
>   together and want to do it with
>   branching so we dont over-write
>   changes and work efficiently.

Non answerable. Generally I would say this is total overkill, but it really depends on the scenario you work in and the langauge you develop in (example: easier to do with WPF than with WinForms). if you work on a website, then - it may be problematic. If you work on a large financial applicaiotn, you may not have too many people trying to check out the same files anyway.

This is totally depending on the context whith you do not provide.

Comment: the only flavor of TFS we can use is with exclusive locks cause this stuff is all out of anyone's hands as i work in a large company and nothing is going to change. so that is why i need direction in concurrent development with a system using exclusive locks.